# Copy a file to all folders batch file?

Tags: windows, windows-7, batch-file

I need copy `credits.jpg` from `C:\Users\meotimdihia\Desktop\credits.jpg` to `D:\Software\destinationfolder and all subfolders` 
I read many and i write

```
/R "D:\Software\destinationfolder" %%I IN (.) DO COPY "C:\Users\meotimdihia\Desktop\credits.jpg" "%%I\credits.jpg"
```

then i save file saveall.bat but i run it , it dont work at all.
help me write 1 bat

Comment: Would PowerShell be okay to do it in? It is integrated from Windows 7 (and is avaiable for XP+)

Comment: what is function i use to copy ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
for /r "D:\Software\destinationfolder" %i in (.) do @copy "C:\Users\meotimdihia\Desktop\credits.jpg" "%i"
```

Of course, if it's to go into a batch file, double the '%'.

Comment: Works like a charm and super simple.

Answer (score 3):

This was the first search I found on google for `batch file copy file to all subfolders`.

Here's a way with [xcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy).
There's also [robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) but that would be too powerful for a simple task like this. (*I've used that for entire drive backups because it can use multi-threading*)

---

But, let us focus on **`xcopy`**.

This example is for saving to a file with the extension `.bat`. Just drop the additional `%` where there is two if running directly on the command line.

```
cd "D:\Software\destinationfolder"
for /r /d %%I in (*) do xcopy "C:\temp\file.ext" "%%~fsI" /H /K
```

- `cd "D:\Software\destinationfolder"` change directory to the folder you want to copy the file to. Wrap this in quotes if the path has whitespaces.
- the `for` loop - [See help here](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html). Or type `for /?` in a command prompt.
- `/r` - Loop through files (recurse subfolders)
- `/d` - Loop through several folders
- `%%I` - `%%parameter`:  A replaceable parameter
- `xcopy` - Type `xcopy /?` in the command line for lots of help. You may need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to read the entire help on this.
- `C:\temp\file.ext` - The file you want to copy
- `"%%~fsI"` - Expands `%%I` to a full pathname with short names only
- `/H` - Copies files with hidden and system file attributes. By default, xcopy does not copy hidden or system files
- `/K` - Copies files and retains the read-only attribute on Destination files if present on the Source files. By default, xcopy removes the read-only attribute.

---

The last two parameters are just examples if you're having trouble with any read-only files and will retain the most important file properties.

[Lots more xcopy parameters here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy#parameters)

[xcopy examples here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy#examples)

---

Just for completeness. This example below will copy the same file in each folder of the current directory and not any sub-folders. Just the `/r` option is removed for it to behave like this.

```
for /d %%I in (*) do xcopy "C:\temp\file.ext" "%%~fsI" /H /K
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use it: Here is a PowerShell solution (PowerShell is integrated in Windows 7 and available from XP and up):

```
$file = "C:\...\yourfile.txt"
$dir = "C:\...\YourFolder"

#Store in sub directories
dir $dir -recurse | % {copy $file -destination $_.FullName}
#Store in the directory
copy $file -destination $dir
```

I'm pretty sure that the last line can be integrated in `dir ...` but I'm not sure how (I do not use PowerShell very often).